# Visual Studio - Razor website cannot find C# class file

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, razor

I have a C# file that contains some code, and I want to refer to it in my Razor HTML page, using the code below:

```
@{
    var check = new pingDevice();
}

//In the main HTML page:

<button onclick="@check.pingDevice().isConnected()">Ping Devices (See Console)</button>
```

When I try to, however, I get the following error:

`CS0246: The type or namespace name 'pingDevice' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

I have the CS file included in my Bin folder, but I still get the same error.

What am I doing wrong? Should I be using a different method of including code in my Razor project?

Comment: Have you put the relevant `using` directive at the top of your html page? It would look something like: `@using MyNamespace`.

Comment: I have tried that, but I get the same error, saying that the namespace name cannot be found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will probably work:

```
<button onclick="@check.isConnected()">Ping Devices (See Console)</button>
```

check is a pingDevice, it probably does not have a function pingDevice().